# Algorithm regarding Computer Vision, circle detection

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

right now I'm trying to learn computer vision but I don't know how to start the algorithm, any pointers would be useful.

[image: Image below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hough Transform is often applied for line detection in edge images. But a variant of it exists that makes it work for circle detection as well. Have a look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform) which provides even the pseudo code.

The general idea is that all edge points of your circles vote for all possible circle parameters (corresponding to circles) that could have caused these points to exist in the image. Afterwards, the circle parameters that have received the most votes (detected either by detecting all local maxima or by iteratively detecting global maxima in the Hough space until the max number of votes drops below a threshold value) yield the parameters defining suspected circles in the image.

Once, you have all circle specifications, you can simply look up the color at the center of each detected circle.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a matrix of white pixels with a non-white circle inside. In order to detect the circle, I would do this way:

```
for(int x = 0; x < matrix.width; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < matrix.height; y++){
        if(matrix[x][y] != white) {
            GetCircleCenter(x, y);
            return;
        }            
    }
}
```

Now, given you know the pixel (x,y) is part of a circle, let's make a method to find its center.

Suppose the pixel you found is marked as yellow. Our objective now is to find the two pixels marked as blue:

[image]

To find this, let's generate two small values v1 and v2, say v1 = v2 = 1.

We now test this:

```
Color c = matrix[x][y];
int v1 = 1, v2 = 1;
while(matrix[x - v1][y] == c) v1 *= 2;
while(matrix[x + v2][y] == c) v2 *= 2;
```

When this method ends, you know that the left blue pixel will be between (x - v1) and (x - v1/2) and the right blue pixel will be between (x + v2/2) and (x + v2). You can perform a binary search to find the exact pixels fast.

When you find both pixels, you know the horizontal center of the circle. Now, do the same thing with the vertical center and you will get the center of your circle.

Answer (score 0):

A circle is a figure of maximum area, with a given perimeter. This can be used for searching. To search for colored objects, you can use the InRange() function. See example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread('calRH.jpg')
blank=np.zeros_like(img)[:,:,0]
#convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#color definition
color_lower = np.array([0,50,33])
color_upper = np.array([180,255,255])
# select only color objects
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, color_lower, color_upper)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, 1, 2)

for cnt in contours:
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    k=4*np.pi*area/(perimeter*perimeter)
    if k>0.86: #test area/perimeter ratio
        print('is circle ',k)
        tmp=blank.copy()
        cv2.drawContours(tmp, [cnt], 0, (255), -1)
        cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 1)
        m=cv2.mean(img, mask=tmp) # mean color circle
        print('mean color', m[0:3])
cv2.imwrite('color_circles.png', img) #save image
```

[image]